# Org-mode filtering PRIORITY=B retrieves all items

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm trying to write a custom block agenda that simply lists all items with priority B:

```
("b" "Priority=B"
  ((tags-todo "+PRIORITY=B"
   ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Priority B")
    (org-tags-match-list-sublevels nil)))))
```

For some reason, this returns an agenda with all of my TODOs. I actually currently don't have anything marked priority B. A custom agenda looking for PRIORITY=A or PRIORITY=C works just fine.

I have the same problem if I just do a standard agenda filter (C-c a m PRIORITY=B). Again, priority A and C work just fine.

Does anybody know why this is happening? Sorry, it's hard to make a minimal working example, since that requires an org file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you don't set the priority, every entry still has one: `org-default-priority`.  Unless you change it, the default priority is "B".  So if your agenda is returning everything *without* an explicitly set priority, it is behaving correctly